# Where does ~/ point in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, directory

I'm starting with Ruby programming and I want to write a small script that involves the creation of a directory.

When I use `system 'mkdir', '-p' '~/.dir'` no directory is created. But when I change it to `/home/name/dir` everything works as expected. As I want to keep the script generic, how can I achieve the usual Unix/Linux semantics of `~/`?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a Dot Dir? It would be hidden in your first command because it is a dot Dir.

Comment: Yes that is intended `ls -lah` gives me all directories I have

Comment: It points to hidden directory `.dir` just under your `root` directory.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer? As I asked for the semantics of ~/

Comment: @nesreka posted my comment as answer.

Comment: Don't be confused by pathnames. They're the same as you'd use at the shell. The shell, though, will play games with them "for your convenience" and will expand things like `~`, which Ruby won't do by default, so you have to tell it you want it to expand the shorthand `~` into the user's home directory. I'd recommend looking at Ruby's [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) class, which is a very convenient wrapper for working with paths and files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, `~` has no special meaning in file paths. Even if it is used inside the parameter of a `system` call, it is not expanded by the underlying shell. Your code should have created a directory literally named `~` inside the current working directory, for example:

```
$ ruby -e 'system("mkdir", "-p", "~/.dir")'
$ ls
~
$ ls -A '~'
.dir
```

You have to use `File.expand_path` to expand the `~` to your home directory path:

```
File.expand_path('~')
# => "/home/toro2k"
```

In your example:

```
system('mkdir', '-p', File.expand_path('~/.dir'))
```

In Ruby you can also use [`FileUtils.mkdir_p`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-mkdir_p) to create directories:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.expand_path('~/.dir'))
```

**Update**: as suggested by the Tin Man my latter example can be rewritten using the [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) class as follows:

```
require 'pathname'
Pathname.mkpath(Pathname.new('~/.dir').expand_path)
```

Comment: I'd highly suggest taking a look at Ruby's built-in [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) class. From the documentation: "All functionality from File, FileTest, and some from Dir and FileUtils is included, in an unsurprising way. It is essentially a facade for all of these, and more."

Answer (score 1):

It points to hidden directory `.dir` just under your user's `root` directory.

here `~/` represents user's `root` directory.

`~` is not related to directory semantics in Ruby.

Comment: `~/` refers to `$HOME/`, which isn't the system's root directory, it's the user's. The system's root would be `/`.

Comment: As an additional note, `~` expands to whatever `$HOME` (in Ruby `ENV['HOME']`) is currently set to, and this can change. It's best not to touch it because it will break a lot of things, but it can be done if necessary.